# Google Fonts - CSS - some characters are not working

Tags: css, html, firefox, google-font-api

I've imported the (in)famous open sans to my CSS. Everything was fine at first.
However, today I noticed that some of the characters `(şğü)` are not being displayed properly in Firefox. They work fine in Internet Explorer and Chrome, but they're being replaced by the default font in Firefox.

I was thinking, this should be a quick-to-solve issue. Any ideas?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);
 p {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<p>Example şğü.</p>
```

Comment: +1 I can confirm the issue, for `ş` and `ğ`, but `ü` seems to be working. I've added a working example to show the issue. Hopefully someone can share some insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, many Google fonts support Basic Latin repertoire only (effectively Windows Latin 1 set); this covers e.g. ü but not the Turkish letters you are using. The repertoire can be selected with checkboxes in the UI of Google Fonts, but this is rather unnoticeable. In this case, you need to add the parameter `subset=latin,latin-ext`:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);

p {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<p>Example şğü.</p>
```

Comment: Then how does it work on other browsers than firefox?

Comment: @Zettam, the code in the question does not work in my IE: “şğ” appears in another font. It seems to work in my Chrome, possibly because Chrome uses a different list of fallback fonts which happens to include Open Sans (which I have installed locally), possibly because it gets a different font file from the Google service. In any case, the method described in my answer is what Google recommends and what works in all browsers (as long as they do `@font-face` in the first place).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I am afraid it doesn't. I am using this subset definition, exactly as you specified, however, all browser display fonts correctly, only Firefox on Ubuntu uses another font to display national characters (Š). Any idea why is that happening?